# How do I tell what messages to handle when subclassing a control?

Tags: winapi

I want to subclass the edit control into a specific case of a masked edit - something that accepts five characters of user input, and displays colons after the first and third characters. I can imagine two basic approaches to this.

I could have the text that the edit control stores be the text I want displayed. In this case, I would need to set the text to L" :  :  " to begin with, and override the messages that detect user input so I could copy it into the correct slots in that string. However, I don't know how to be sure which messages those are. I assume WM_KEYDOWN is one, but if there are others, and I don't think of them all, input that triggers the messages I missed would incorrectly defer to the edit control's default handling.

Alternatively, I could have the text that the edit control stores be the text the user enters - no colons. In that case, I would need to override the way the control is displayed so I could to generate a string that includes colons based on the stored text, and draw that when drawing the control. I assume this would mean replacing the WM_PAINT handling. The problem with that is that it would seem to require redefining *everything* about how the control looks myself, when the text is the only part I want to change. I'm not confident I could do that perfectly, and I would certainly rather not.

How should I approach this?

Edit: I've tried overriding WM_PAINT like this:

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK MaskedEditProc(HWND hwndDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam,
    UINT_PTR  uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    if (message == WM_PAINT)
    {
        WCHAR userInput[6];
        Edit_GetText(hwndDlg, userInput, 6);
        WCHAR displayString[]{L" :  :  "};
        int userInputLength{ Edit_GetTextLength(hwndDlg) };
        switch (userInputLength)
        {
        case 5:
            displayString[6] = userInput[4];
        case 4:
            displayString[5] = userInput[3];
        case 3:
            displayString[3] = userInput[2];
        case 2:
            displayString[2] = userInput[1];
        case 1:
            displayString[0] = userInput[0];
        }
        Edit_SetText(hwndDlg, displayString);
        DefSubclassProc(hwndDlg, message, wParam, lParam);
        Edit_SetText(hwndDlg, userInput);
        return TRUE;
    }
    return DefSubclassProc(hwndDlg, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

This seems to basically work, except for some reason it causes the displayed text to flicker.

Edit 2: I set the control's text to L"0:00:00" from its parent window, and gave it the following window procedure:

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK MaskedEditProc(HWND hwndDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam,
    UINT_PTR  uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CUT:
        return 0;
    case WM_PASTE:
        return 0;
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        if (wParam == VK_DELETE)
        {
            WORD caretPosition{ LOWORD(SendMessage(hwndDlg,EM_GETSEL,0,0)) };
            switch (caretPosition)
            {
            case 7:
                return 0;
            case 1:
            case 4:
                SendMessage(hwndDlg, EM_SETSEL, caretPosition + 1, caretPosition + 2);
                break;
            default:
                SendMessage(hwndDlg, EM_SETSEL, caretPosition, caretPosition + 1);
            }
            return DefSubclassProc(hwndDlg, WM_CHAR, '0', 0);
        }
    case WM_CHAR:       
        if (wParam == '\b')
        {
            WORD caretPosition{ LOWORD(SendMessage(hwndDlg,EM_GETSEL,0,0)) };
            switch (caretPosition)
            {
            case 0:
                return 0;
            case 2:
            case 5:
                SendMessage(hwndDlg, EM_SETSEL, caretPosition - 2, caretPosition - 1);
                break;
            default:
                SendMessage(hwndDlg, EM_SETSEL, caretPosition - 1, caretPosition);
            }
            return DefSubclassProc(hwndDlg, WM_CHAR, '0', 0);
        }
        else if (iswdigit(wParam))
        {
            WORD caretPosition{ LOWORD(SendMessage(hwndDlg,EM_GETSEL,0,0)) };
            switch (caretPosition)
            {
            case 1:
            case 4:
                SendMessage(hwndDlg, EM_SETSEL, caretPosition + 1, caretPosition + 2);
                break;
            default:
                SendMessage(hwndDlg, EM_SETSEL, caretPosition, caretPosition + 1);
            }
        }
    }
    return DefSubclassProc(hwndDlg, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

This seems to work as intended, though my backspace key has always been broken, so I haven't tested that part. The control is also set not to accept non-digit input, so I don't think the fact that I don't handle those here should break anything.

Comment: You may get some inspiration from `CMFCMaskedEdit` control ([afxmaskededit.h](https://github.com/Samangan/mpc-hc/blob/master/src/thirdparty/mfc/afxmaskededit.h), [afxmaskededit.cpp](https://github.com/Samangan/mpc-hc/blob/master/src/thirdparty/mfc/afxmaskededit.cpp)).

Comment: @zett42 I didn't know MFC code was available for perusal. Is the basic control library also? It seems like this would be easy if I had the option to copy Microsoft's handling for some choice messages verbatim into my subclass and making a couple small alterations.

Comment: You can get full MFC source code for free by downloading Visual Studio community edition. The basic control library is not officially available as source, but you may have a look at ReactOS and Wine source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you handle only WM_CHAR (and possibly custom messages related to your masking). Leave the arrow keys alone, let the edit control handle them and in your WM_CHAR handler query for the caret placement. In your WM_CHAR when the placement would normally reach a colon send a EM_SETSEL that skips to the next character location.

Comment: WM_CHAR includes presses of shift/tab/backspace/delete/etc. as well as characters that display, right? It just occurred to me that if I take this kind of approach, I'll have to handle backspace and delete specially, or the user will be able to delete my colons.

Comment: Common mistake: Failure to acknowledge the mouse interface, e.g. pasting content, or selecting all and the choosing *cut* from the context menu.